# Telerik Premium Collection - how to get back the link

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, telerik

Early this week I hit 10k in SO and I saw the Telerik Premium Collection offer. I decided to check it out later at home. But after few hours the "Rep" moderation job ran and I lost about 300 points (Telerik Promo ad disappreared).

[alt text http://john.cognitivedelay.com/images/free-telerik.png#](http://john.cognitivedelay.com/images/free-telerik.png#)

Now I am back to 10k rep but I no longer see the telerik promo offer. Will it appear again?

Sorry if this is a duplicate. Searched but no luck.

Comment: Git yer sockpuppets in order, pronto!

Comment: There are quite a few advertisements listed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery Though not the Telerik one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this page:

https://www.telerik.com/registration-login/stackoverflowregistration.aspx

Comment: [Bookmark link]....done!